# how to import data file (json, jsx, js, etc) for react native ios?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a data file something like this.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Car",
    "personal_require": 1,
    "public_serve": 1,
    "public_require": 1,
    "personal_serve": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "House",
    "personal_require": 1,
    "public_serve": 1,
    "public_require": 1,
    "personal_serve": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Finance",
    "personal_require": 1,
    "public_serve": 1,
    "public_require": 1,
    "personal_serve": 1
  }
]
```

I use import and it works for web, but for iOS it seems the system won't able to find the file. I got error:

> Failed building JavaScript bundle. Unable to resolve module
> ../**tests**/data/defaultWishlist.json from
> /Users/wlin/dev/wishlist/screens/ServeScreen.tsx:
>
> None of these files exist:   * defaultWishlist.json   *
> **tests**/data/defaultWishlist.json/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
> 15 | import WishlistItem from "../components/WishlistItemText";   16 |
> import { Wishlist } from "../types";
>
> > 17 | import * as defaultWishlist from "../**tests**/data/defaultWishlist.json";
> > |                                   ^   18 |   19 | type ServeNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<ServeParamList,
> > "ServeScreen">;   20 | type Props = { Warning: Problem checking
> > watchman version. Invalid Version: 20210524.

I have tried json, js, ts, jsx... none of them work.
Full code is here: https://github.com/dotku/aladdin/tree/iosBundleFail

Comment: Have you tried `require` instead?

Answer (score 0):

As what I've seen you were trying to import it wrongly.

To fix this change your defaultWishlist.js to defaultWishlist.json
then don't use export inside the json file.

Example of /**tests**/data/defaultWishlist.json:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Car",
    personal_require: 1,
    public_serve: 1,
    public_require: 1,
    personal_serve: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "House",
    personal_require: 1,
    public_serve: 1,
    public_require: 1,
    personal_serve: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Finance",
    personal_require: 1,
    public_serve: 1,
    public_require: 1,
    personal_serve: 1,
  },
]
```

Then you can use this json on every file as long as you call it:

```
const list = require('./___test___/defaultWishlist.json');
```

Here's a reproducible snack: [Snack Example](https://snack.expo.io/@xsephtion/json-export)

Edit:
Just to add if you were trying to import it as a JS file. The structure should be like this:

```
const export data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Car",
    personal_require: 1,
    public_serve: 1,
    public_require: 1,
    personal_serve: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "House",
    personal_require: 1,
    public_serve: 1,
    public_require: 1,
    personal_serve: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Finance",
    personal_require: 1,
    public_serve: 1,
    public_require: 1,
    personal_serve: 1,
  },
]
```

then on your file you are going to call it like this:

```
import {data} from './___test___/defaultWishlist.js'
```

Comment: I did tried wha you said, including .js and .json by both require and import. Both of them failed on build stage. Web build are all working, but iOS build failed with the same error: `Failed building JavaScript bundle.`. Did you start the sample code I shared?

Comment: @WeijingJayLin you can try renaming your folder from '___test___' to 'test'. And make sure that your file path is correct. I.e.: iff you are accessing it on App.js then it should be require('./test/defaultWishlist.json') assuming that you renamed the folder.

Comment: I don't see any different between 'test' and 'test'? are you talking about '_ _test_ _` to 'test'?

Comment: yes ' _ _ test _ _ ' to 'test'. Stackoverflow automatically removes the underscore